# Pivot table with multiple tables

Tags: pivot-table, powerpivot

I have what I think should be a fairly straightforward situation. I have a table like this:
[image]

and I want to plot the counts of start dates and end dates per month, for **every** month in a sequence (but in a way that I can also do filtering by other columns, etc.).

To do this, I tried:

- Created a list of months:

[image]

- Added it to the data model
  [image]
- Added the table of items to the data model
  [image]
- Created relationships between the date columns and the list of months:
  [image]
- Created a pivot table with the Rows as the Months - up to and including this point everything works as I'd expect:
  [image]
- Now when I try to add End Date to the Values, you can see that the Row Labels are the values in the Start Date field instead of the End Date field as I'd expect:
  [image]

What I'd want to see is the list of months in the MonthList as the Row Lables, and the counts of the End Dates that occur in each month, along with zeros for those months in which there are no items with the End Date of that month. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create two relationships referring to the same table, one is active and one is inactive. This is why one line is dotted in the relationship diagram. That relationship is inactive.

In order to use an inactive relationship, you must create your calculation using the `USERELATIONSHIP` function.

You must create a separate measure for each relationship, to ensure the right relationship is being used.

So, in the main table, these measures:

```
Count of items:=count(data[Item])


Count of item start dates:=CALCULATE(
    [Count of items],
    USERELATIONSHIP(dates[Date], data[Start Date])
)

Count of item end dates:=CALCULATE(
    [Count of items],
    USERELATIONSHIP(dates[Date], data[End Date])
)
```

I found [this page](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/multiple-relationships-between-tables-in-dax/) to be very useful.

[image]

[image]

I also created a column in the Dates table (which is a list of dates between 1/1/2020 and 12/31/2021, not a list of months):

[image]

Of course you can format dates however you want, but I used this:

```
=FORMAT([Date],"YYYYMM")
```

To get the pivot table to show zeroes for missing months, you need to select these options:

PivotTable Options>Display>Show items with no data on rows = checked/ticked

PivotTable Options>Layout & Format>For empty cells show = 0

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It works as expected, but I'm not totally clear what's happening. Can you explain what the 3 measures are for? Is the 'count of items' just like a dummy object that then you can use to reference in the other two dummy measures just to establish the relationship? Or is the count() critical/doing something special?

Comment: Yes, it's just to make it easier to read the others. You can just as easily put count(data[item]) into each of the other calculations. It could also count any other field providing it's fully populated. I just figured item was the simplest thing to count/ Ultimately in PP you can create specific calculations with very explicit behaviors. It's a slightly different way of thinking than normal pivot tables, but much more powerful.

Comment: The other two are not "dummy measures" per se - but an explicit calculation forcing the use of a specific relationship. It's tricky to start with Power BI and PP because we're so used to thinking in terms of DB relationships and this doesn't really work the same way exactly.